# The parameter passed to the function in ARM 32 bit assembly language

Tags: c, assembly, arm, calling-convention

When calling a function `void foo (int *x) { … }` from ARM 32-bit assembly, the parameter passed to the function foo must be in r0, where r0 contains a signed integer or the address of an integer?

Comment: If the function's argument is declared to be a pointer, then the value in r0 should be interpreted as a pointer, yes.  Either the address of an integer (or an array of integers), or 0 for a null pointer.  You have to read the documentation for `foo` to find out what it expects about the memory whose address you pass it.

Comment: The prototype `int *x` indicates that `r0` should contain the address of a signed 32-bit integer, if that was the question. `int *` for address, `int` for value.

Comment: This depends on the specific ABI and C compiler. I don't think there's a consistent ABI across all ARM parts.

Comment: @Lundin: Sure, but wherever it's passed, it's a pointer not the integer itself.  (And many do pass the first integer/pointer arg in `r0`.)  Some calling conventions add indirection (e.g. passing a struct as a pointer to memory allocated by the caller, instead of as values), but they can't remove it without breaking programs!  And there's no reason for any calling convention to add a level of indirection for an `int*` arg which fits in a register or in 4 bytes of stack space.